# Ошибка при выполнении миграции (Oracle DB)

Tags: php, laravel, миграция, oracle19c

Есть следующии данные:

```
    public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::create('users',function (Blueprint $table){
           $table->increments('id');
           $table->string('email',255)->nullable(false)->unique('email');
           $table->string('password',255)->nullable(false);
           $table->string('remember_token',100)->nullable(true);
           $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

После выполнения команды **php artisan migrate**, данные и правда вносятся в БД, но появляется следующая исключение:

```
Migrating: 2022_04_10_204900_user_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  Error Code    : 955
Error Message : ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
Position      : 16
Statement     : create sequence users_id_seq minvalue 1  start with 1 increment by 1
Bindings      : []
 (SQL: create sequence users_id_seq minvalue 1  start with 1 increment by 1 )

  at D:\Development\PHP\Laravel_Projects\Mini_site\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:712
    708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
    713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    714▕             );
    715▕         }
    716▕     }

  1   D:\Development\PHP\Laravel_Projects\Mini_site\vendor\yajra\laravel-pdo-via-oci8\src\Pdo\Oci8\Statement.php:183
      Yajra\Pdo\Oci8\Exceptions\Oci8Exception::("Error Code    : 955
Error Message : ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
Position      : 16
Statement     : create sequence users_id_seq minvalue 1  start with 1 increment by 1
Bindings      : []
")

  2   D:\Development\PHP\Laravel_Projects\Mini_site\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:501
      Yajra\Pdo\Oci8\Statement::execute()
```

Почему это возникает и как избежать данной ошибки?

Comment: Это случайно не попытка задублировать таблицу `users`?

Comment: Нет. Так как до этого база была полностью пустая. Я даже дропнул на всякий случай после первого раза, но эффекта это не дало

Comment: Просто по умолчанию миграция для этой таблицы уже лежит в `database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php`. И ошибка `ORA-00955` указывает что пытается что-то задублироваться (например, таблица)

Comment: В ошибке написано что users_id_seq уже была создана для другого объекта БД. Смотрите [тут](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/issues/245) описание этого бага для Laravel.

Comment: Проблема была sequence, после удаления которых в БД проблема исчезла! Всем спасибо за помощь!